# Parâmetro GET com caracteres especiais

Tags: php, post, get, caracteres

Já vasculhei a internet inteira atrás da solução do meu problema e como último recurso, venho cá perguntar a vocês e espero encontrar uma solução para o meu problema, seguinte:

Estou efetuando uma consulta via PHP & MySql com os seguintes parâmetros passados na URL `../data/status.php?projeto=108&origem=Sugestão de Melhoria`

Ao "depurar" o meu código ao lado do back end ( PHP ) percebo que ele realmente monta a query da forma correta conforme abaixo:

```
string(883) "SELECT mantis_bug_table.version   AS VERSAO, 
   CASE 
     WHEN mantis_bug_table.version <> '' THEN 
     Replace(mantis_bug_table.version, '.', '') 
   END                        AS VERSAOSEMPONTO, 
   CASE 
     WHEN mantis_bug_table.status IN ( 10, 20, 30, 50 ) THEN 'EM EXECUÇÃO' 
     ELSE 'CONCLUÍDO' 
   END                        AS DESCRICAO, 
   Count(mantis_bug_table.id) AS QUANTIDADE FROM   dbmantis_bugs.mantis_bug_table 
   INNER JOIN dbmantis_bugs.mantis_custom_field_string_table 
           ON ( mantis_bug_table.id = mantis_custom_field_string_table.bug_id ) WHERE  ( mantis_custom_field_string_table.value = 'Sugestão de Melhoria' ) 
   AND ( mantis_bug_table.project_id = 108 ) GROUP  BY mantis_bug_table.version, 
      descricao ORDER  BY mantis_bug_table.version ASC, 
      status ASC "
```

Mas ao executar a query ele simplesmente não me retorna dado nenhum:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

E ao pegar está mesma query e executar no banco obtenho os seguintes resultados:

> NULL    CONCLUÍDO   13
>
> 1.0.0.x   100x    CONCLUÍDO   2
>
> 1.0.1.x   101x    CONCLUÍDO   7
>
> 1.0.2.x   102x    EM EXECUÇÃO 1
>
> 1.0.2.x   102x    CONCLUÍDO   9
>
> 1.0.3.x   103x    EM EXECUÇÃO 5
>
> 1.0.3.x   103x    CONCLUÍDO   5
>
> 1.0.4.x   104x    EM EXECUÇÃO 1
>
> 1.0.4.x   104x    CONCLUÍDO   1

Segue o meu código PHP: http://pastebin.com/NF4p7sDz
Segue o código de conexão: http://pastebin.com/ajSWtyBA

PS: Ao utilizar qualquer outro parâmetro na origem que não contenha caracteres especiais, por exemplo GRI, os resultados são printados na tela da maneira correta sem problema algum.

```
../data/status.php?projeto=108&origem=GRI
```

Comment: Dê um `var_dump()` nos seus parâmetros para que seja possível ver como tem que ser tratado, e poste na sua pergunta.

Comment: @KennyRafael Fiz uma correção na query publica aqui, segue o resultado da var_dump nos meus parâmetros: string(21) "Sugestão de Melhoria" string(3) "108"

Comment: Se está chegando dessa forma não é problemas com encoding...não está tendo problemas com a conexão não? sugiro postar o código de conexão e consulta...

Comment: @KennyRafael exatamente está a minha dúvida, pois não é problema de encoding, nem de conexão pois se eu trocar o parâmetro para qualquer outro que não contenha espaços ou caracter especial exemplo GRI, VARIAVEL, funciona :(, código de conexão adicionado ao post, agora a parte de "consulta" dita por ti, não entendi.

Comment: É verdade, esqueci que trocando funciona, de qualquer forma acho válido postar a consulta, ou seja, toda a parte que monta a sua `query`

Comment: @KennyRafael Então, a query é montada "na mão" eu estou passando os parâmetros pelo próprio navegador, acessando o arquivo e passando os parâmetros, inclusive ao digitar sugestão de melhorias como parâmetro o navegador monta a requisição da seguinte maneira : blabalbalba/status.php?projeto=108&origem=Sugestão%20de%20Melhoria

Comment: Sim, mas no seu script `php` você pega todos os parâmetros e insere na `sql` certo? como você faz isso?

Comment: @KennyRafael Faço como mostrado no arquivo http://pastebin.com/NF4p7sDz, apenas recupero o parâmetro pelo $_GET  atribuo ele a uma variável e coloco a variável dentro da query String WHERE (mantis_custom_field_string_table.value = '$origem')